# PHP script for retrieving MySQLi data returns empty page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve all the rows from my MySQL database through a PHP script. I'm pretty sure connecting to the database went well, but the code that needs to be run afterwards doesn't get executed (or so it seems). Even if the script couldn't return any data, it should at least return an empty array, but when I open the file, it shows an empty page with no text at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Retrieve all rows from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM u8338p5759_iosdb.Posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$dataArray = Array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Assign each row into an array
    $dataArray[] = $row;

}
echo json_encode($dataArray);

} else {
    echo json_encode($dataArray);
}

// Close the connection
$conn->close();
```

Comment: First change your `$row * $result->fetch_assoc()` to `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` and make sure $conn is established.

Comment: How stupid of me! I actually had the correct code running perfectly fine a while back, and when I tried to move everything to a new FTP server, I had to retype the code by hand (copy/pase didn't work), and I accidentally put a "*" where I needed a "=". I've been going through my code character by character to see what went wrong, but I missed this little mistake every single time. Thanks for noticing and my apologies for my clumsiness! :)

Comment: @AnowarHossainJeebon By the way, I just added the connection code to my post, so you can see if I did that right. I double-checked to make sure all the variables in the mysqli parameters are matching my database credentials.

Comment: yes now it's okay as you say your database credential is okay. I have checked in my local by:
`$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');`
Full code is working. Nice :)

Comment: @AnowarHossainJeebon So does it actually work for you? Are you seeing the JSON array? When I try to view the page in my web browser I just get a blank page. I can't find any errors in the error log and all my credentials are matching. This is so frustrating. Do you have any experience with fixing this kind of problem?

Comment: yes i have. Open your browser if firefox check in `inspect element->net`, if google chrome check `inspect element->network`.

Find your in network request after submit. Check request and response form there.

Comment: @AnowarHossainJeebon Ah, never mind! I got it! Turns out I was using the wrong PHP settings. I was using native PHP and I had JSON and MySQLi disabled in my web hosting admin account. Just set it to PHP 7.0 and enabled JSON and everything worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row * $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           ^----
```

Exactly what do you think this multiplication operation should be producing? "undefined variable times array" isn't exactly a useful operation.